# How do I remove files as a result of the find command?

Tags: bash, find

I want to `rm` all the files that I get when I run

```
find search-3S-beta |grep "\.log\."
```

What would be the command?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Find can do the deletion for you using the `-delete` option. Combining the rest of your command into a single `find` line, this will become:

```
find search-3S-beta -name '*.log.*' -delete
```

Comment: or `find  search-3S-beta -name '*.log.*' -print0 |xargs -0 rm`

Comment: Why would you do that instead of `find ... -delete`?

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker "Feature [...] `-delete` Added in `4.2.3`" (from `find(1)`) But yeah, I don't see any use either. Just use `-delete` if available.

Comment: 4.2.3 was released over 8 years ago, in 2004. So this is available even at the slowest updaters by now.

Comment: Because it is more efficient.

Comment: No, it is not. You need to type more, so it's not efficient on your fingers, and you're launching an extra process to do the deletion, so it's not more efficient for the computer either.

Comment: @McNisse It's really inefficient as Dennis says. The shell has great powers like here with piping and the use of `xargs`, but doing things programmatically is preferred for performance reasons. Avoid it when it's not needed. And, *please post alternatives as answers, rather than comments*.